# Using the Line command with a bound on distance between points

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

Suppose I use the `Line` command applied to a list (or more accurately apply `Graphics[Line[list]]` or `Graphics3D[Line[list]]`). Is there some way to only connect points which are less than a certain Euclidean distance in the list?

A silly example:

Take

`list1 = Flatten[Map[ReIm, Table[(1)*E^({j}*I*Pi/60) + (-2), {j, 0, 120}] ], 1];` and `list2 = Flatten[Map[ReIm, Table[(1)*E^({j + 4}*I*Pi/60) + (2), {j, 0, 120}] ], 1];`

and compare the outputs of `Graphics[Line[Join[list1, list2]]]` and`Show[Graphics[Line[list1]], Graphics[Line[list2]]]`

The lists I usually work with would give rise to something like the first command with an "extra" line connecting them but no easy way in general to separate the lists into sublists and apply a command of the second type. However, these types of "extra" lines are much longer than the lines I actually want, namely the lines approximating both circles. Is there some nice way to stop Mathematica joining points which are over some distance, say, $l$ apart?

Comment: how about `r = .1;NearestNeighborGraph[N@Join[list1, list2], {All, r}, VertexSize -> 0]`?

Comment: or `l12 = Join[list1, list2]; Show[Graphics[Line[l12[[#]]]] & /@ FindCurvePath[l12]]`?

Comment: .. or `ListCurvePathPlot[l12]`?

Comment: @kglr These all seem like they will work in the case of 2D graphics, and I am grateful. Is there a something similar to  `FindCurvePath` in 3D?

Comment: `NearestNeighborGraph` should work in 3D.